# Rails Cross Origin Headers Set, XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.d1.com/sign_in, Origin something is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, browser, cross-domain

I am making an Ajax POST Request from a different origin to my server for user logins. I have properly set the Cross Origin headers in my application_controller.rb:

```
def set_access_control_headers

  if request.options?
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' 
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true"
  end
end
```

But I'm still getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.d1.com/sign_in. Origin http://www.d2.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't properly setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin or Access-Control-Request-Method Response headers, according to the current spec.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin needs to be a specific domain. If you have multiple domains that should be allowed access, consider using a server-side white-list of domains or subdomains to match the Request Origin against, and if the Request Origin matches an entry in the whitelist echo the Request Origin as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Response Header value.

And then set Access-Control-Request-Method Response header to be the Methods you wish to allow, e.g.: GET, POST, OPTIONS